# how do you delete an object allocated with placement new

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation

there are quite a few faces for the new operator in c++, but I'm interested in placement new.

Suppose you allocate memory at a specific memory location

```
 int memoryPool[poolSize*sizeof(int)];
 int* p = new (mem) int; //allocates memory inside the memoryPool buffer

 delete p; //segmentation fault
```

How can I correctly deallocate memory in this case?
What if instead of built-in type int I would use some class called myClass?

```
 myClass memoryPool[poolSize*sizeof(myClass )];
 myClass * p = new (mem) myClass ; //allocates memory inside the memoryPool buffer

 delete p; //segmentation fault
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Placement new doesn't *allocate* memory. It constructs an object in the supplied raw memory. So you'd need to call the destructor of said object directly before using the appropriate deallocation method.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you have an array for `poolSize` objects, but only "allocate" a single one out of it. I hope you don't do exactly the same when "allocating" any other objects as you will then have two pointers pointing to the exact same entry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first case, there's no point in using placement new, since `int` doesn't have a constructor.

In the second case, it's either pointless (if `myClass` is trivial) or wrong, since there are already objects in the array.

You use placement new to initialise an object in a block of memory, which must be suitably aligned, and mustn't already contain a (non-trivial) object.

```
char memory[enough_bytes];  // WARNING: may not be properly aligned.
myClass * c = new (memory) myClass;
```

Once you've finished with it, you need to destroy the object by calling its destructor:

```
c->~myClass();
```

This separates the object's lifetime from that of its memory. You might also have to release the memory at some point, depending on how you allocated it; in this case, it's an automatic array, so it's automatically released when it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

In your case there is no need to deallocate it, your int array will be deallocated once you return from your function. You should only call explicitly your destructor:

> p->~myclass();

---

to keep you buffer correctly aligned use std::aligned_storage, look in here for example:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/aligned_storage/

Comment: so what do I do in the first case? int*p?

Comment: Well, your array (int this case) is stack allocated so there is no need to free / delete this memory.

Comment: what if it were allocated on the heap using new[] ?

Comment: Then you would have to call `delete[] pMyAllocatedBuffer`, after calling destructor. Or rather `p = operator new(buffSize)` and `operator delete(p);`