# operator delete throwing an exception with placement new

Tags: c++, heap-memory

I am trying to understand operator new and placement new.
This is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class simpleClass
{
    int objID;

public:
    simpleClass(int ID)     // constructor
    {
        objID = ID;
        cout << "Constructing object with ID: " << objID << endl;
    }

    void printID()
    {
        cout << "Object ID: " << objID << endl;
    }

    ~simpleClass()
    {
        cout << "Destructing object with ID: " << objID << endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    void *ptrToMem = operator new(sizeof(simpleClass)*3);              
    simpleClass *simpleClassPtr_1 = new (ptrToMem)simpleClass(1); 
    simpleClass *simpleClassPtr_2 = new ((simpleClass*)ptrToMem + sizeof(simpleClass))simpleClass(2);
    simpleClass *simpleClassPtr_3 = new ((simpleClass*)ptrToMem + sizeof(simpleClass)*2)simpleClass(3);

    simpleClassPtr_1->printID();
    simpleClassPtr_2->printID();
    simpleClassPtr_3->printID();

    simpleClassPtr_1->~simpleClass();
    simpleClassPtr_2->~simpleClass();
    simpleClassPtr_3->~simpleClass();
    operator delete(ptrToMem);

    return 0;
}
```

I am simply trying to allocate memory for 3 objects and then call placement new on them.
Everything seems to work fine until the operator delete where it gives me an exception (in VS2013).

What am I doing wrong?
Is it not allowed to call operator delete when using placement new?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do you delete an object allocated with placement new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21551972/how-do-you-delete-an-object-allocated-with-placement-new)

Comment: a glaring problem is you're incrementing your pointer more than you need to. either do `ptrToMem + sizeof(simpleClass)` or `(simpleClass*)ptrToMem + 1`

Comment: Thank you but that question only shows to call the destructor and not freeing the memory.

Comment: BTW, create a [mcve]. You would have found out that with a single element, your code works, but with more elements it fails!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem here is use of the pointers.

This two lines are wrong:

```
simpleClass *simpleClassPtr_2 = new ((simpleClass*)ptrToMem + sizeof(simpleClass))simpleClass(2);
simpleClass *simpleClassPtr_3 = new ((simpleClass*)ptrToMem + sizeof(simpleClass)*2)simpleClass(3);
```

It should be like this:

```
simpleClass *simpleClassPtr_2 = new ((simpleClass*)ptrToMem + 1)simpleClass(2);
simpleClass *simpleClassPtr_3 = new ((simpleClass*)ptrToMem + 2)simpleClass(3);
```

Since pointer increase by one increases address by size of the pointed object so extra `sizeof` is not needed.
You were exceeding range of allocated memory size, so it ended with a crash.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing the allocated storage out-of-bounds:

```
(simpleClass*)ptrToMem + sizeof(simpleClass)
```

This should just be `+ 1`. Remember, pointer arithmetic works in steps of the pointee size anyway.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You messed up your pointer arithmetic:

```
simpleClass *simpleClassPtr_2 = new ((simpleClass*)ptrToMem + sizeof(simpleClass))simpleClass(2);
simpleClass *simpleClassPtr_3 = new ((simpleClass*)ptrToMem + sizeof(simpleClass)*2)simpleClass(3);
```

You are running placement new on the wrong element. Instead of initializing the adjacent `simpleClass`, you are constructing a simpleClass number `sizeof(simpleClass)`. The simplest thing is to replace the casting with char* casting:

```
simpleClass *simpleClassPtr_2 = new ((char*)ptrToMem + sizeof(simpleClass))simpleClass(2);
simpleClass *simpleClassPtr_3 = new ((char*)ptrToMem + sizeof(simpleClass)*2)simpleClass(3);
```

This works both with GCC and Clang.